# accessibility - large text resource directory qualifier?

Tags: android, resources, accessibility, qualifiers

Do we have resource directory qualifier that is used when the user set large (or other) text size? This setting is located in the Accessibility section. I use "sp" pixels but there is one situation (fixed table) when I need to know if the text is bigger then the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. Font scale is not among our [available qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources). You can get [the `fontScale`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#fontScale) at runtime, though.